# How to pass string with symbol ";" from CustomActionData to a CustomAction using WiX?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have deferred CustomAction in C# and another one to pass some properties to it.

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1"
              Property="CustomAction2"
              Value="EncryptedString=[ENCRYPTEDSTRING]"
/>
```

However, if the property contain symbol ";" then

```
string encString=session.CustomActionData["EncryptedString"];
```

outputs only part before ";", because this symbol is considered as a delimiter between properties.
Is there any workaround to pass strings containing ";" ?

for example

```
ENCRYPTEDSTRING="12;3474dsfgee"
```

and output

```
encString="12"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use DTF's CustomActionData; it assumes the custom action items are delimited by semicolons. Instead, grab CustomActionData directly and don't bother with the `EncryptedString=` prefix.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can I grab CustomActionData from my deferred custom action?

Comment: Use the session indexer: `session["CustomActionData"]`

Answer (score 0):

I will just add as an answer to get proper links. These may be helpful for implementing what Bob Arnson suggests:

- **Recommended**: [**How to Access Windows Installer Property in Deferred Execution**](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-access-windows-installer-property-deferred-execution)
- [Basic Differences in "Execute Immediate" and "Execute Deferred" CA](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/basic-differences-execute-immediate-and-execute-deferred-ca?sym=TRUE)
- [Everything About Properties [Wise Package Studio]](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/everything-about-properties-wise-package-studio)